# Google dfp and windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, google-dfp

Today my pm asked me if it was possible to add dfp into windows 8 application (.net). 
I have not found anything on the web that could positively answer to this question.

I had a look at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/fundamentals which is only for android and ios. And also http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ec777fa0-c4c7-4130-b1a2-0c9a8666fab5/google-dfp-metro-apps which is for html5/js and seems to not have any clue to solve the question.

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exists an .net API for DFP...maybe you can try to port it

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dfp-dotnet/

I have no experience with this lib, but normaly porting a normal .net library to WP8 is not so heavy (if there are no, or not so much ThirdParty references in it)...